# Playfield with binary file

Tags: c++, bin

I am programming a board game and I have  to make a binary file called "write" that always writes the current playfield. It contains information like the active player, the biggest and the smallest x/y coordinate. Fields without tokens on it should have the value zero. It has to be done so that the program can be tested automaticly easier.

I thought about making a class called CurrentField that I write in my binary file after every turn, but I'm not sure how I can ensure that everything will be written in the place where it needs to be (we have to declare a specific header and certain things are expected to be in a certain offset).

Any ideas about that? Good idea, or is there a better way to do this?

Edit: And does anyone know a way of testing what really has been written to the binary file?
Edit2: It has to be solved with c++ standart libraries. 
The performance is not that important since it will not be a large file. The idea of writting only if a command is entered is good.

Comment: Are you asking about "how do I write to binary file"? What are "tokens"? Sorry for asking more questions instead of giving answers.

Comment: Yes, I do ask for a good way to write in a bin file what I want. My approach was to write a class which updates itself. Still I'm not sure if that s a precise way to do it.

Comment: Why do you care about classes, this is a last thing that matters. Write byte by byte. Do you need to write anything what is larger than byte? Do you need singed or unsinged numbers? I'm just wasting your time, but I'm hope you don't mind.

Comment: I can't just write byte by byte because it has to be up to date on every turn. So if I write "active player: 1", "biggest x coord: 7" etc it has to be up to date. I thought it's easier to write a class that is automatically uptodate.

Comment: And nvm, appearantly times is worth nothing when learning to code.

Comment: What is "times"? What stops you from erasing file on every update?

Comment: Actually I don't know. Just realized that indeed I can do it like " file << Active Player; " and it will post the up to date version. And it will just replace the bin and write it new every once in a while. Genious lol. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two good libraries that can help you with that.

1. [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is designed to serialize some arbitrary structures. It includes some good concepts as versioning (you may opt to change the stored data in an update of your game and leave the former game state intact) and `archive`s (what if you'd like to change the file format at all?
2. [Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html) is designed to parse and serialize with great speed any text and binary protocols. It works a lot faster.
3. You can workaround any issues just storing the memory location in file with [file-memory mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). Be careful with pointers, though.

Check if you really need to do this on every step, as filesystem calls are quite slow. At least, do it asynchronously (look for [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm only allowed to use c++ standart libraries and it has to be a binary file. The file will not be large as there is a maximum of 8x8 fields, so performance won't be an issue. Thanks for your help so far.